# access to assignments - userid (power automate)

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-planner

i want to find out the assigned persons from a teams task.
Following sample shows me the first one (because index 0). but how can i get all assigned persons?

```
item()?['_assignments'][0]['userid']
```

Comment: You got some JSON or something?  Waaaaaaay more context required.  What do you want to do with them once you've got them?  Can't help at present without further info.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with many tries:

```
join(xpath(xml(json(concat('{"body":{"value":', item()?['_assignments'] , '}}'))), '/body/value/userId/text()'), '; ')
```